# Error: Node Sass version 5.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0 (After using this command : "npm install node-sass@4.14.1" still throws a same error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, sass

enter code here I've created a react project, using command : npm create-react-app

*Installed*

node-sass: "^5.0.0"
react: "^17.0.1"

Then I tried to import blank index.scss file to index.js componenet

**Screenshot Code of Index.js**

```
[Code of Index.js][1]
```

**Screenshot of Localhost**

[image of localhost having the description of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNmq2.png)

**Special Note :**
After getting this I Have uninstall node-sass and installed again with version4+. Please find below screenshot of cmd.

npm uninstall node-sass
npm install node-sass@4.14.1

[cmd screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eb5lO.png)

Comment: You can try it 
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install node-sass@4.14.1

Comment: Please, post an [mcve] in text directly in the question's description, avoid images of code.

Comment: **Node-Sass** is **depricated**. Install Dart-Sass instead!

Answer (score 0):

Please uninstall it an then install the last version of 4:

> npm uninstall node-sass

> npm install node-sass@4.x

Comment: I have tried this but still the issue is not resolved, after installing "npm install node-sass@4.x" lots of error has been dispplayed.

Comment: Yes, then after I have started installing "npm install node-sass@4.x"

Answer (score 0):

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install node-sass@4.14.1
```

Or, if using yarn (default in newer CRA versions)

```
yarn remove node-sass
yarn add node-sass@4.14.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not go back. That’s quitting.

rm -rf ./node_modules ./package-lock.json

Then

npm i

Done ✅

Answer (score 0):

Try installing sass instead of node-sass.

```
yarn remove node-sass
yarn add sass
```